# Cannot get SQLite SELECT statement to work in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

I wrote an object that lets me use Phonegap's database more easily. The part for the SELECT statement is as follows:

```
/********************
 * Database SELECT: *
 ********************/
global.select = function(query)
{
    var resultSet = null;

    db.transaction(function(tx){ // Do SQL stuff here:
        tx.executeSql(query, [], function(tx, results){ // Success:
            // When results are there:
            if(results != null)
            {
                // return them for using them:
                resultSet = results;
                alert("Results are here: " + results);
            }
            // In all other cases:
            else
            {
                // Return false (error):
                return false;
            }
        }, function(error){ // Error:
            global.logError(error);
        });
    }, function(error){ // Error:
        global.logError(error);
    }, function(){ // Success:
        consoleLog("SELECT complete!");
        alert("Return would be: " + resultSet);
        return resultSet;
    });
} // <-- global.insert = function(query)
```

The part giving me a headache tries to select everything from a table using the function above. The problem I run into is that by doing this, I get asynchronous behavior that is beyond me...

Here's the code trying to select stuff:

```
var results;
if( results = db.select('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 1') )
{
    alert("Result in index.html success: " + results);
    // Do stuff with query results here...
}
else
{
    alert("Result in index.html failure: " + results);
}
```

When executing this, the

```
alert("Result in index.html failure: " + results);
```

is the first output I see. It seems to execute before the select has even started. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I'm not sure how to return the results from the SELECT-function. Since there are nested functions, I don't know how to handle that gracefully. Any ideas on that part?

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These callbacks *are* asynchronous; this is how WebSQL was designed.

`db.select` returns before the data is available; any code that accesses the data must be inside the `executeSql` or `transaction` callback functions, or in a function called from there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! So in other words it's impossible to make database calls a little easier with the above mentioned approach? Is there another way I can achieve this? For now, I'll do it 'the hard way'. ;)

Comment: Database calls are never easy; you always have to chain multiple functions together.

Comment: Okay, thank you again + I accepted your answer. For those facing the same problem: I ended up using code templates to create the code... Not perfect, but way better than coding it from scratch every time! :)